Cannot produce blocks on time after switching to async backing

The situation is somewhat amusing. There are three collators: A produces X blocks, B produces Y blocks, and C produces Z blocks. The average block time is 18 seconds, meaning two slots are missing. Only one collator can produce a block in a given period.
I followed this wiki (https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-async-backing) to upgrade our testnet. The relay chain is Rococo, and the PR is https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/pull/1492.

Left some infos here for the future people: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/4589
